# How to abort a net.Dial call in Go?

Tags: go

I have a client who try to connect to a server.

I need to be able to terminate the client and abort this Dial attempt. Is this possible ? How could I do that ?

The timeout is apparently longer than 30s since the test blocks until the 30s elapse without a failure of the Dial call.

Can we specify a timeout ourself ?

Comment: You are looking for a way to provide another timeout or you want to cancel due to another non time based situation?

Comment: Have you looked at https://blog.golang.org/context package?

Comment: According to the documentation, context is for request processing that we must be able to cancel or is limited in time. My app is not a request handler. My app has multiple concurrent clients running in different go routines. I implemented my own variant of context that allows to terminate a group of go routines. This works well, except for goroutines locked in a dial attempt. Normally, on unix a connect attempt doesn't last long if there is no remote server. In Go it seam to last at least 30s. How can I terminate a go routine blocked in a Dial attempt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`net.Dialer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer) has `Timeout` and `Deadline` fields, and also can use a context with [`DialContext`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Dialer.DialContext) which allows for timeout and cancelation.

You can refer to [`DialTimeout`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#DialTimeout) to see how to setup the basic Dialer:

```
func DialTimeout(network, address string, timeout time.Duration) (Conn, error) {
    d := Dialer{Timeout: timeout}
    return d.Dial(network, address)
}
```

And an example with a `context.Context`:

```
var d Dialer
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 5*time.Second)
defer cancel()

return d.DialContext(ctx, network, address)
```

Comment: Excellent. That is what I was looking for. I was using the example given in the Overview. `conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "golang.org:80")`. I didn't look in the right place.